# How to log processes in daemon-mode?

Tags: process, logs, daemon

I would like to save the standard output of the program motion in a text file. If I don't use motion in daemon-mode I would simply do it by:

```
motion > log.txt
```

But what is the equivalent when I run it in daemon-mode? I cannot specify implicit logging at least according to motion's man page.

Comment: @jordanm What you say is not true.  Programs of various sorts can close the `stdout` or `stderr` but there is absolutely no necessity for the daemon to do so.

Answer (score -1):

In this context the word `daemon` means just, that after forking the parent-process exits. So, if the newly created daemon still logs data on `STDOUT` respectively `STDERR` redirection should work as you would expect in the non-daemon case.

If `motion` closes `STDOUT` and `STDERR` after forking you have no chance to log anything (`motion` have to) since nothing can be written by `motion` to `STDOUT` or `STDERR` anylonger.

If the execution of `motion` and `motion -magicdaemonswitch` only differs in the way that with `-magicdaemonswitch` a fork is made. You should be fine to start `motion` with

```
motion > log.txt &
```